# Nginx says file not found when requesting PHP file on different root

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I am using a different root for the path `/cloud` but whenever I try to request any `/cloud/*.php` file nginx says 404 file not found. I can access `/cloud/*.html` without any problem. I can even access any `/*.php` but somehow not on `/cloud`. My configuration file looks like

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        server_name _;


        location /cloud {
                root /home/fhost/public_html;
        }
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: it can't merge `location`s `/cloud`+`\.php$`, so it needs another complex `locaton` like `location ~ ^/cloud/[^/.]+\.php$` or nested `\.php$` with the own `root`s.

Comment: @Deadooshka I tried your rule `location ~ ^/cloud/[^/.]+\.php$ {}` similar to `location ~ \.php${}` in my configuration but result is still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP with two roots, you will need a `location` block for each. The cleanest solution is a nested location block within a `location ^~ /cloud` block. Note the use of the `^~` modifier that makes this prefix `location` take precedence over the other `location ~ \.php$` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

```
location ^~ /cloud {
    root /home/fhost/public_html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }
}
```