# Nginx can't map URL to directory outside of the root

Tags: nginx

I have a PHP site that's running fine. Now I need to add URL `/adminer/` that is mapped to a directory outside of the root and there I have an `index.php` file that needs to be executed. I have following config (Debian 9.7):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/usr/www/xxx.xxx/web/app/www;
    index index.php;

    server_name xxx.xxx;

    location /adminer {
        root /home/usr/www/xxx.xxx/web/adminer;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/xxx.xxx.php7.0-fpm.socket;
    }
}
```

When I open `http://xxx.xxx/adminer/` I always get 404. I am trying for more than a hour different configs but can't find a working way. Thanks

Comment: Firstly, the path is constructed by concatenating the value of `root` with the URI. So if `/adminer/` is already part of the URI, it doesn't need to be part of the `root`. Try: `root /home/usr/www/xxx.xxx/web;`. Secondly, you need a nested location to process your PHP URIs under the second root. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/868382/nginx-says-file-not-found-when-requesting-php-file-on-different-root/868404#868404).

Comment: Thanks, I would swear that I tried something like you mentioned :) If you want, you can place your comment as answer and I will accept it or I will place the config that worked. @RichardSmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Richar Smith's](https://serverfault.com/questions/950910/nginx-cant-map-url-to-directory-outside-of-the-root?noredirect=1#comment1236155_950910) comment, this is a working config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/usr/www/xxx.xxx/web/app/www;
    index index.php;

    server_name xxx.xxx;

    location /adminer {
        root /home/usr/www/xxx.xxx/web;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/xxx.xxx.php7.0-fpm.socket;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/xxx.xxx.php7.0-fpm.socket;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it wouldn't work for me for URLs like /adminer/something-else. I ended up using alias [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42467562/870060)