# nginx alias or root in location is being ignored

Tags: nginx

I need to serve CodeIgnitor from `/app/rsvp/dev/admin`.

All requests to /admin [should be appended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45634423/605748) to /admin/index.php (except for static assets). The main site files are in `/app/rsvp/dist` (also PHP).

Alias seems to make the most sense but the alias/try_files combo is [long standing bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). I've tried the suggested solutions but none worked so far.

As suggested by commenters a nested root value and second php location does partially work. I believe the issue is now with the try_files value.

With the below, a request to /admin/screenings/index, shows this in the script log --

`log_format  scripts '$request $status > $document_root$fastcgi_script_name ? $query_string';`

> GET /admin/screenings/index HTTP/1.1 502 > /apt/rsvp/dev/admin/index.php ? /admin/screenings/index

Interesting that the returned status is 502. The main site doesn't get this error.

Is there a way to debug the location blocks (apart from the scripts log)? As in which location blocks get hit by requests.

```
server {
  listen  80;
  server_name  _;

  root  /app/rsvp/dist;
  index  index.php;

  location ^~ /admin {
    root  /app/rsvp/dev;
    try_files  $1  /admin/index.php?$request_uri;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files  $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass  php:9000; # docker
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      include  fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO  $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files  $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass  php:9000; # docker
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include  fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO  $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is with the other `location` block. You need to use `root`, but you also need a nested location for PHP. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/868404/316685).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following:

```
location ~ ^/admin(.*)$ {
    root /app/rsvp/dev;

    try_files $1 /admin/index.php?$request_uri;
}
```

Here we capture the end of the URL path to a variable, and use it in `try_files` as the file path.

Comment: Script log looks good but error log shows `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting`

Comment: Yes, this actually causes a redirect cycle, because `/admin/index.php` matches the `location`. Could you add clear examples of requests and where the response should come from the filesystem? Please add the examples to the question.

Comment: I've updated the post. I used a nested regex location `location ~ \.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$` for the assets which seems to work ok

Comment: The actual paths where the requests should be sent from are missing. An example what I need: `https://example.com/path/to/file` needs to be sent from `/var/www/some/path`. With these pairs I can see what are the request - path pairs, and then the configuration can be adjusted to match those.

Comment: Looking at the htaccess (previous server), all path requests need to be appended to the root index.php eg `/app/rsvp/dev/admin/index.php?/admin/user/login`